# How can I improve opencv Bounding Box Alg. in python?

Tags: python, opencv

Here's a summary about what do u wont to get, and what I have done so far right now and the output.

**What do I want to get**

I would like to measure the diameter distribution of the oranges on field during harvest.

**What do I have**

(Sorry that the comments are in spanish, I bet whoever is reading this has no doubt about the code)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Lectura y reescalado de la imagen
img = cv2.pyrDown(cv2.imread('Ampli1 No numbers.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED))

# Parametrización de la imagen y escala de grises
ret, threshed_img = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),
                127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
# Encontrar los contornos quedarse con el de arriba

contours, hier = cv2.findContours(threshed_img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#image, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(threshed_img, cv2.RETR_TREE,
#                cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Con cada contorno, dibujamos un rectángulo delimitador en verde verde

# a minAreaRect in red and
# a minEnclosingCircle in blue

for c in contours:
    # Hacer el contorno delimitador 
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    # Dibujarlo en verde
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # coger el de area mínima.

    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    # convertir todas las coordenadas-puntos flotantes en integers. 
    box = np.int0(box)
    # Dibujar un rectangulo 'nghien' rojo.
    cv2.drawContours(img, [box], 0, (0, 0, 255))

    # realizamos el cirulo de area mínima
    (x, y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    # Convertir todos los valores a integer
    center = (int(x), int(y))
    radius = int(radius)
    # dibujamos el circulo en azul
    img = cv2.circle(img, center, radius, (255, 0, 0), 2)

print(len(contours))
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (255, 255, 0), 1)

cv2.imshow("contours", img)

cv2.imshow("contours", img)

while True:
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27: #ESC ape para romper el bucle
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

With all this done I would like to increase the number of oranges detected and compare the known distance of the billiar ball on the box to the oranges and getting the diameter. Also ignore any object who is bigger/smaller than the oranges so I dont really know what can i do to improve the segmentation.

Here the final example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sGEZ.jpg)

Comment: Your first task is to deal with separating the oranges. Since the oranges overlap, this is not trivial.  I would suggest looking into watershed.  See https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html

Comment: AI is a cure-all. I would expect instance segmentation to be able to solve this well.